# POST http://localhost:5000/users/signin 500 (Internal Server Error) trying to make auth works

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongoose, redux, axios

When I post the data for my Auth the console throws this error ** 500 (Internal Server Error) ** I think the problem is with my server, first check the database and the data is in the cluster
but the data does not work in my client. I know that this type of problem is often on the server. I've been searching for several hours and I can't figure it out.

This is the index

```js
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import cors from 'cors';

import postRoutes from './routes/posts.js';
import userRoutes from './routes/users.js';

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '30mb', extended: true }))
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: '30mb', extended: true }))
app.use(cors());

app.use('/posts', postRoutes);
app.use('/users', userRoutes);

const CONNECTION_URL = '**THIS_IS_MY_MONGO_DB;
const PORT = process.env.PORT|| 5000;

mongoose.connect(CONNECTION_URL, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
  .then(() => app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server Running on Port: http://localhost:${PORT}`)))
  .catch((error) => console.log(`${error} did not connect`));

mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);
```

The users.js route

```js
import express from 'express';

import { signin, signup } from '../controllers/user.js';

const router = express.Router();

router.post('/signin', signin);
router.post('/signup', signup);


export default router;
```

The user controller

```js
import bcrypt from "bcryptjs";
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";

import User from "../models/user.js";


export const signin = async (req, res) => {
    const { email, password} = req.body;

    try {
        const existingUser = await User.findOne({ email });

        if(!existingUser) return res.status(404).json({ message: "El usuaruio no existe."});

        const isPasswordCorrect = await bcrypt.compare(password, existingUser.password);

        if(!isPasswordCorrect) return res.status(400).json({ message: "Credenciales invalidas."});

        const token = jwt.sing({ email: existingUser.email, id: existingUser._id }, 'test', { expiresIn: "1h" });

        res.status(200).json({ result: existingUser, token});
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({ message: 'Algo salio mal.' });
    }
}

export const signup = async (req, res) => {
    const { email, password, confirmPassword, firstName, lastName } = req.body;

    try {
        const existingUser = await User.findOne({ email });

        if(existingUser) return res.status(400).json({ message: "El usuaruio ya existe."});

        if(password !== confirmPassword) return res.status(400).json({ message: "Las contraseñas no coinciden."});

        const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 12);

        const result = await User.create({ email, password: hashedPassword, name: `${firstName} ${lastName}` })

        const token = jwt.sing({ email: result.email, id: result._id }, 'test', { expiresIn: "1h" });

        res.status(200).json({ result, token});
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({ message: 'Algo salio mal.' });
    }
}
```

The index api

```js
import axios from 'axios';

const API = axios.create({ baseURL: 'http://localhost:5000' })


export const fetchPosts = () => API.get('/posts');
export const createPost = (newPost) => API.post('/posts', newPost);
export const likePost = (id) => API.patch(`/posts/${id}/likePost`);
export const updatePost = (id, updatedPost) => API.patch(`/posts/${id}`, updatedPost);
export const deletePost = (id) => API.delete(`/posts/${id}`);

export const signIn = (formData) => API.post('/users/signin', formData);
export const signUp = (formData) => API.post('/users/signup', formData);
```

Comment: If you clearly look at userController file you will find jwt.sing method , which must be jwt.sign.

Comment: Wow, man, you saved my night. I couldn't figure it out, I was burning out my eyes reading the code. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

```js
export const signup = async (req, res) => {
    const { email, password, confirmPassword, firstName, lastName } = req.body;

    try {
        const existingUser = await User.findOne({ email });

        if(existingUser) return res.status(400).json({ message: "El usuaruio ya existe."});

        if(password !== confirmPassword) return res.status(400).json({ message: "Las contraseñas no coinciden."});

        const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 12);

        const result = await User.create({ email, password: hashedPassword, name: `${firstName} ${lastName}` })

        // you have typo in next line
        const token = jwt.sing({ email: result.email, id: result._id }, 'test', { expiresIn: "1h" });
        // replace it by:
        const token = jwt.sign({ email: result.email, id: result._id }, 'test', { expiresIn: "1h" });

        res.status(200).json({ result, token});
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({ message: 'Algo salio mal.' });
    }
}
```